# How to remove the default highlight effect when clicking on a ListView item and replace it with a custom highlight effect (Icon mode)?

Tags: c, listview, winapi

When you click on a ListView item, the selected item is highlighted. What I want to do is to remove this default highlight effect and replace it with a custom highlight effect.

First I want all the items to have a border of a certain color:

[image]

And then when I click on an item, its color changes:

[image]

Comment: Custom-draw the ListView by subclassing it to handle the [`NM_CUSTOMDRAW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774865.aspx) notification message.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff919569(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You don't need to subclass anything to use custom draw notifications, parent will receive them in a form of WM_NOTIFY.